# comparing and setting date model attributes from two different collections with backbone.js, marionette.js, Lo-dash, moment.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette, momentjs, lodash

i have made a function that will execute before save i have two collections Phase and Staff
when the start date of a phase is changed i am trying to find all staff models that have the same startdate as the original phase startdate that was changed and update those staff models to the new phase date

problem i am having is that users can change many dates/values at once.

starting data

Phase A: Nov10

Phase B: Nov10

Staff A: Nov10

Staff B: Nov10

user changes to

Phase A: Nov5

Phase B: Nov1

Staff A: Nov1

Staff B: Nov1

*both staff dates should favor the earlyer date

the key in the array phaseDateHasRelatedFields 
is the enrollmentPhaseID

how can i be sure the earliest possible date will be assigned

```
    checkForPhaseDate: function () {
        var proceed = Q.defer(),//start promise
            phaseTab = this.getTab('details').phaseListView,
            staffTab = this.getTab('details').staffListView,
            phaseModels = phaseTab.listView.collection.models,
            staffModels = staffTab.listView.collection.models,
            staffCollection = staffTab.listView.collection,
            phaseCollection = phaseTab.listView.collection,
            phaseDatesChanged = _.where(phaseModels, function (Model) {
                return Model.hasChanged('PhaseStart') && Model.isNew() !== true;
            }),
            phaseDateHasRelatedFields = _.reduce(phaseDatesChanged, function (result, model) {
                result[model.get('EnrollmentPhaseID')] = _.where(staffModels, function (m) {
                    return moment(m.get('StaffStart')).isSame(moment(model._originalValues.PhaseStart));
                });
                return result;
            }, {});
        if (this.model.isNew()) {//if the enrollment is new continue save
            proceed.resolve();
        } else if (phaseDatesChanged.length === 0) {//if no changes have ocurred with phaseDates continue save
            proceed.resolve();
        } else if (phaseDateHasRelatedFields.length === 0) {//if no related fields are found continue save
            proceed.resolve();
        } else if (phaseDatesChanged.length > 0) {//if we have phaseDates changed and related dates found ask user for actions
            require(['components/modal/modal'], function (Modal) {
                return new Modal({//display our popup to the user for confirmation of actions
                    title: common.loadTemplate('#phaseChangeDateDialogTitle', $templates),
                    content: common.loadTemplate('#phaseChangeDateDialogBody', $templates),
                    positive: {//yes change the matching dates and save all changes
                        caption: common.lang('Yes'),
                        callback: function () {//iterate through found related record dates
                        _.forEach(phaseDateHasRelatedFields, function (staffArray, phaseId) {
                            var currentPhase = phaseCollection.get(phaseId);//get the phase we are associated with
                            _.forEach(staffCollection, function (staffModel) {//loop through the staffs and get the associated record row
                                if (currentPhase) {//if the assoc record was found
                                    staffModel.set({ StaffStart: currentPhase.get('PhaseStart') });
                                }//set the new phase date to the the staff model 
                            });
                        });
                        proceed.resolve();
                        }
                    },
                    negative: {//leave current changes as is do not change other dates continue save
                        caption: common.lang('No'),
                        callback: function () {
                            proceed.resolve();
                        }
                    },
                    cancel: {//cancel changes and cancel save fully
                        callback: function () {
                            proceed.reject('User Cancelled');
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
        }
        return proceed.promise;
    }
```

Comment: If the whole issue is "how do I loop over a collection without knowing its length", check out `for (key in object)` construct for objects or `array.forEach()` function of arrays. (Of course with arrays you always know the `array.length`.)

Comment: thanks i have added that to the example but i am still not sure how to be sure the earliest possible date will be assigned.

Comment: Please create [a minimal verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) instead of posting all surrounding code. As for finding a minimum in a collection with Lo-Dash, have a look at [_.sortBy()](https://lodash.com/docs#sortBy).